# Bootstrap Select not working inside Bootstrap Vue Modal

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vue-component, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using Bootstrap Vue with Bootstrap select and the select works perfectly outside the modal
It doesnt open at all inside the modal. Live code is [HERE](https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/NoyxgY)

JS file

```
Vue.component("suluct", {
  template: "#suluct",
  props: {
    week: [String, Number],
    year: [String, Number],
  },

  mounted() {
    const $selectpicker = $(this.$el).find('.selectpicker');

    $selectpicker
      .selectpicker()
      .on('changed.bs.select', () => this.$emit('changeWeek', this.options[$selectpicker.val()]));
  },

  updated() {
    $(this.$el).find('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  },

  destroyed() {
    $(this.$el).find('.selectpicker')
      .off()
      .selectpicker('destroy');
  },

  computed: {
    options() {
        // run some logic here to populate options
      return [
        {
        title: "Sunday",
        value: "sunday",
      }, {
        title: "Monday",
        value: "monday"
      }
      ]
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <suluct></suluct>

  <div>
    <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>

    <!-- Modal Component -->
    <b-modal id="modal1" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
      <suluct></suluct>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="suluct">
  <select class="form-control selectpicker bs-select">
    <option
      v-for="(option, index) in options"
      :key="index"
      :value="option.value"
      :selected="option.selected">
      {{ option.title }}
    </option>
  </select>
</script>
```

The dropdown select wont open at all. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. After trying various ways, I found a solution.

When you wanna show modals, don not use **v-b-modal** directive.

Create a method, using **this.$bvModal.show()** to show modals.

And then you should use **this.$nextTick([callback])** .

Final, use javascript to call bootstrap-select in the callback method
The method will be like

Html

```
<b-btn @click="ShowModal">Launch demo modal</b-btn>
```

Js

```
...
ShowModal() {
    this.$bvModal.show('modal1');
    this.$nextTick(()=>{
        $('select').selectpicker();
    })
},
...
```

ps:Sorry for my poor English and hope you can understand what I mean